# How do I run a python command with arguments repeatedly?

Tags: python-3.x, shell, command-line-interface, arduino-uno

I have downloaded a program from Github a Ubuntu/Python program to produce Talkie voice files (LPC) from Audio .wav files.
https://github.com/berrak/wav-files-to-arduino-talkie-lpc#python-language-installation
But the problem is that I have to manually do it from the CLI, as it only allows one file to be processed at a time.
I have at least 43 files to do, so this is SLOW.

I would like to put this into a python script that calls the CLI repeatedly with a list of files names attached to the CLI.
I have no control over the arguments given in the command line.
The CLI is `python3 python_wizard -S -T tms5220 -f arduino ae.wav >> wavelpc.h`

I need to change the ae.wav file to the files I need to process in the script.
I am quite happy to repeat the same command in the script, and manually change the file name to what it should be, but this does not work in python.
But I have tried some suggestions on various websites, but to no avail.
I have no programming experience in Python, so I am a bit lost!

I tried the Rumpy process, and the import sys, subprocess to no avail.
It just comes up with errors I don't understand.

Comment: Why'd you _like to put this into a python script_ rather than a simple shell script?

Comment: Yes, if that does the job. What is the difference between a shell script and  a python script?

Comment: A _shell script_ is executed by a shell, while a _python script_ is executed by a Python interpreter.

Comment: What do you mean by _a list of files names attached to the CLI_?

Comment: The 43 file names are all .wav music files, you can only run one at a time with this command line. So how do you run 43 one after another?

Comment: That doesn't answer any part of my question. In what form is this _list_ supplied? How is this _list_ _attached to the CLI_? Actually, you seem to contradict this you wrote by saying that _you can only run one at a time with this command line_, so not _a list_.

Comment: All I have is 43 wave files in the same directory as python_wizard. I have only the command line as quoted by the author, which processes one file at a time. It does not accept a list of file commands in .py file. How do I get it to call all the CLI including the setting repeatedly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer which is  to use a BASH script.
The Original advice from the author was to include some python commands at the beginning, but when I stripped these out, the CLI line now works and takes each file name and executes the call to python_wizard, updating the file and then executing the next command
The command is in the form of

```
python3  /home/stephena/python_wizard/python_wizard -S -T tms5220 -f arduino ae.wav >> wavelpc.h
```

I changed the filename of the .wav file on each line.
The `>>` adds to the file rather overwriting it.
The File name is Fredall.sh
and to execute it I change directory to the python_wizard directory and run the following command

```
bash Fredall.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

> All I have is 43 wave files in the same directory as python_wizard. … How do I get it to call all the CLI including the setting repeatedly?

If there are no other wave files in the directory, you can

```
for file in *.wav
do  python3 python_wizard -S -T tms5220 -f arduino "$file"
done >>wavelpc.h
```

(if you really want to append the output to `wavelpc.h` - otherwise use `>wavelpc.h`).